# Como fazer uma paginação com JavaScript que mostre somente 6 registros por página?

Tags: javascript, paginação

Quero fazer uma paginação com JavaScript, e nessa paginação gostaria de mostrar apenas 6 registos por página.

Aqui esta um exemplo de como eu estava fazendo anteriormente, mas os meus registos ficaram muito grandes e agora fica inviável ver todos completamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pq não usa algo pronto como DataTables.net faz paginação, busca, ordenação, etc

Comment: Olá, o codigo que mostrou não está a fazer varias tabelas? reparo que a tag <table> está dentro do while e falta aberturas e fecho de tags.

Comment: Não isto apenas esta a fazer uma única tablea tabela.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código ao invés da imagem dele?

Comment: Pretende fazer paginação diretamente mysql ou em javascript?
A pagina é apenas essa tabela ou vai ficar dentro de outra tag exemplo div?

Comment: Vai ficar dentro de uma div, e eu gostava que tipo a paginação aparece-se com dados vindos da base de dados.  e que aparece-se unicamente a imagem e o titulo !!